# array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given issue

Tags: php, fat-free-framework, array-flip

This is my code.

```
$param = array('email');

$this->getMapper()->copyfrom('POST',function($val) {

    return array_intersect_key($val, array_flip($param));

});
```

And I get the error in title `array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given issue`

If I put directly

```
return array_intersect_key($val, array_flip(array('email')));
```

it works.

[Framework is F3, v. 3.5.0].

THank you

Comment: Simple scope issue: see the docs -http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe it will work.

```
$param = array('email');

$this->getMapper()->copyfrom('POST',function($val) use ($param) {

    return array_intersect_key($val, array_flip($param));

});
```